# Traverse an expression tree and extract parameters

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda, traversal

I'm writing a kind of a mapping tool. I have a method that looks like this (simplified):

```
   public void RegisterMapping<TTarget, TSource>(string propertyName, 
                                                 Expression<Func<TSource, object>> memberMap)
```

The `memberMap` is an expression defining how to transform a property from `TSource` to `TTarget`. For the business logic, I need to extract all references to properties of `TSource` from  it. For example, from

```
x => x.Customers.Where(c => c.Orders.Any())
```

I would like to get `Customers`, and from

```
x => x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName
```

`FirstName` and `LastName` (could be as string[], `PropertyInfo` is trivial to convert to).

How would I do this? My first approach was to traverse the tree manually, checking the node type and inspecting different properties depending on the node type (e.g. `Operand` for unary expressions, `Arguments` for a function call) to determine of any of these are a property of `TSource`. Then I discovered the [expression kind list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions(v=vs.110).aspx) and I gave up -- even if I support only the most common kinds, it's still lots of work. Then I found the [ExpressionVisitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx). It looks better, but it's still a lot of work to override the visitor methods and I'd like to know if there's an other option, using perhaps a more specialised framework, before I devote my time to this.

Comment: Look at the `ExpressionHelper` code of ASP.MVC team: (https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ExpressionHelper.cs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think as you've said that using [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) works out to be a good approach. You don't need to implement all the `Visit...` methods as they already have a default implementation. From what I understood what you want is to find all property accesses of a certain type inside a lambda function

```
public class MemberAccessVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Type declaringType;
    private IList<string> propertyNames = new List<string>();

    public MemberAccessVisitor(Type declaringType)
    {
        this.declaringType = declaringType;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> PropertyNames { get { return propertyNames; } }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression expr)
    {
        if (expr != null && expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            var memberExpr = (MemberExpression)expr;
            if (memberExpr.Member.DeclaringType == declaringType)
            {
                propertyNames.Add(memberExpr.Member.Name);
            }
        }

        return base.Visit(expr);
    }
}
```

This could be further improved to what you want by checking the member is a property and also to get `PropertyInfo` rather than strings

It could be used as follows:

```
var visitor = new MemberAccessVisitor(typeof(TSource));

visitor.Visit(memberMap);

var propertyNames = visitor.PropertyNames;
```